# might get arrested

Tags: modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

a. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might get arrested.

b. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might have gotten arrested.

Are both  grammatically correct?

I think (a) means:

1. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they would possibly get arrested.

and (b) could mean the same or it could also mean:

2. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they had probably been (already) arrested.

In '2' the arrest takes place before the criticism.

Is that correct?

Comment: You might want to know that "get arrested" is informal for "be arrested".

Answer (score 1):

> the arrest takes place before the criticism. Is that correct

No. While b **could** possibly be used when the arrest occurred first, without additional context it would not be understood that way. The normal meaning is the same as a. To indicate the prior arrest one might say:

> In those days, if someone criticized the government, they had probably already been  arrested.

The problem with

> a. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might get arrested.

is that "might have gotten" seems to be looking forward from the moment of the speech to the possible arrest, using a conditional form to discus an event long determined, but whose outcome is unknown. "Get" here is a present form, generally used to describe future events, because the point-of-view is placed after the speech and before the possible arrest.

> b. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might have gotten arrested.

This is using a present perfect form, to indicate a sequence of events, but it feels a bit akward to me. 'Have gotten" is a purely US form, and is one often misused and thus regarded with suspicion by some.  [This *Ask the Editor* page](https://learnersdictionary.com/qa/difference-between-have-got-and-have-gotten) describes the ways in which it is used, and b isn't quite any of them.

I would express the sense of both a and b with:

> c. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might have been arrested.

or perhaps

> c2. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might well have have been arrested.

just for emphasis. Another form, a bit strounger, is:

> d. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they would probably have been arrested.

stronger yet is

> d. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they would have been arrested

"Would have " expresses an event in the past  supposed to have occurred, but not known to have actually occurred. It is used for deductions or suppositions about past events, so it fits well here, and avoids the issue of "gotten". It is also natural in both UK and US English.

Comment: might have been arrested=standard English. might get arrested: informal English; might have gotten arrested: informal AmE; might have got arrested, informal BrE

Comment: @Lambie  Yes but "might have been" is a present perfect form, while "might get" is the simple present. the corresponding form using "get" is "might have got" or "might have gotten" and I thing the version using "be" is better here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I don't think they are both correct. Sentence **2** actually makes more sense than the first one and it even looks better on the grammar scale

First sentence should be like :

> In those days, if someone criticized the government, they could get arrested

OR

> In those days, if someone criticized the government, they could have gotten arrested

Comment: `they might got arrested` << Is "might got" grammatical?

Comment: @user1677 No, it isn't. Perhaps it is a typo on Atrin Noori's part.

Comment: Or a very insufficient knowledge of English!

Comment: @user1677 Oh yeah Thanks for noticing... no it is not

Comment: You don't explain why you think form a incorrect or these forms are better.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Sorry I don't get it

Comment: @Atrin Noori  You wrote "I don't think they are both correct." and "First sentence should be like" But you did not explain **what** was incorrect, or **why** your changes were improvements. That doesn't help the OP, or other readers, to learn much. By "form a" I meant the first example sentence in the question,, which the OP labelled "a".

Answer (score -1):

I believe both the statements mean almost the same. But have made a grammatical correction for the 2nd sentence :

> a. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might get
> arrested.

a means `In those days, if someone criticized the government, they would possibly get arrested`.

> b. In those days, if someone criticized the government, they might
> have got arrested.

b means `In those days, if someone criticized the government, it is more certain that they would get arrested.`

Comment: "might have got" is not a natural form. If it isn't an actul error of grammar, it sounds like one. it is not an improvement here.